# Social Travel App for managing Itinerary

Tags: mobile-apps, travel-tools

I am looking for a Travel app where i can keep and manage my itinerary, get to know about other people travelling, maps and restaurants search.

Searching on the net i found World mate has shut down. Any ideas for alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For itinerary management, I go with [TripIt Pro](https://geo.itunes.apple.com/us/app/tripit-travel-organizer/id311035142?mt=8&at=10l4B9&ct=TSE) that is by far the best at integrating reservation emails from various sources and keeping you up to date on changes to flights.

For finding local restaurants and places to visit, [Trip Advisor](https://geo.itunes.apple.com/us/app/tripadvisor-hotels-restaurants/id284876795?mt=8&at=10l4B9&ct=TSE) is a good resource to have handy just about anywhere.

For hotels, well I recommend [the Agoda.com app](https://geo.itunes.apple.com/th/app/agoda-great-prices-on-hotels/id440676901?mt=8&at=10l4B9&ct=TSE) but as developing that is actually my job, you could consider that recommendation biased. But if anyone has a reason some other app is better, let me know and we'll fix that!

For free offline maps with navigation while traveling, I find [MAPS.ME](https://geo.itunes.apple.com/us/app/maps-me-offline-map-nav/id510623322?mt=8&at=10l4B9&ct=TSE) generally reliable ... but you're well advised to have a *variety* of mapping programs available if you're going outside major cities, as the quality and accuracy of their data vary *wildly.*

Getting to know other travelers, well personally I think the point of traveling is to get to know the *locals* so I'm not active on any, but if I was into that I'd probably pick [Travello](https://geo.itunes.apple.com/us/app/travello-app/id924774827?mt=8&at=10l4B9&ct=TSE) as they run contests for sharing content regularly -- right now there's one on to win a Parrot Bebop drone, which is an alright piece of kit.

One class of app I do like to travel with that most people overlook is astronomy apps, to figure out what's in the sky in strange places -- [NightSky](https://geo.itunes.apple.com/us/app/night-sky/id475772902?mt=8&at=10l4B9&ct=TSE) and [Skyview](https://geo.itunes.apple.com/us/app/skyview-free-explore-the-universe/id413936865?mt=8&at=10l4B9&ct=TSE) are my choices there!

Comment: @ZachLipton Oh, is that rude around here? On Stack Overflow you pretty much always get upvoted if you link to your own posts with more details. OK, ditched those links!

Comment: Yep, I can certainly do that!

Answer (score 3):

There's no one answer for this, even though plenty are trying. Mostly, getting traction is difficult, while every individual's needs are just too different to easily define a lowest common denominator.

You should check out [TripIt](https://www.tripit.com), designed to keep all your travel plans together, integrating with your email inbox, and [its alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/tripit/).

Also worth checking out is [Esplorio](https://esplor.io).